Gradle D8 Compilation Error: Merging DEX File with Classes Prefixed 'j$' in Flutter Project
I'm experiencing an issue with my Flutter project when trying to build it using Gradle. The build fails with the following error:
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
ERROR: /home/abadidi/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/56c9a3fbcd208cf82b6416faec55188a/transformed/jetified-desugar_jdk_libs-2.0.4/classes.dex: D8: Attempt at compiling intermediate artifact without its context
ERROR: D8: com.android.tools.r8.internal.Ge: Merging DEX file containing classes with prefix 'j$.' with other classes, except classes with prefix 'java.', is not allowed: _COROUTINE.ArtificialStackFrames, _COROUTINE.CoroutineDebuggingKt, _COROUTINE._BOUNDARY, _COROUTINE._CREATION, android.annotation.SuppressLint, android.annotation.TargetApi, android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Default, android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub$Proxy, android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub, android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$_Parcel, android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback, android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Default...

What went wrong:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

Here is my app/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' apply false
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.example"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
        exclude("META-INF/INDEX.LIST")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/license.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/NOTICE")
        exclude("META-INF/NOTICE.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/notice.txt")
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.example"
        minSdk = 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64', 'x86'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
    implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.window:window:1.0.0"
}

Here is my project-level build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.24'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Here is my gradle.properties file:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=true
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.vfs.watch=true
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-bin.zip

I've tried updating all dependencies and ensuring that multiDexEnabled is set to true, but the issue persists. Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
defaultConfig {
       
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

I also changed compileOptions and kotlinOptions to java 17, the issue persists

The interesting line is the one after Error while merging dex archives: which is not included in your post.

@Robert there was nothing after the two points

That would be very uncommon. usually the error message two lines after contains the class name that exists twice like here: https://github.com/KasperskyLab/Kaspresso/issues/258
